# alternative way to linq GroupBy to improve speed of query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, group-by

i have some product category which can inherit to more grade (in my project i have max 4 grade). for example (1)Digital_Product-> (2)Mobile-> (3)Android-> (4)Sony

i want to select 2 newest product from each root category (grade 1). i used below query but it processed in 1800ms. the problem is groupBy query. when i delete Groupby, it processed in 100ms.

```
        IEnumerable<Db.Article> _List = uow.ArticleRepository.Get().Where(x =>
                            x.ArticlePropertyValues.Any(c => (_Status == "All" || c.ArticleProperty.Key == _Status))
                            && x.IsActive == true
                            && x.IsDeleted == false
                            && (_Type == -2 || x.ArticleCategory.TypeID == _Type)
                             ).GroupBy(p => p.ArticleCategory.ParentID == -1 ?
                                            p.ArticleCategory.ID :
                                            (p.ArticleCategory.ArticleCategory1.ParentID == -1 ? p.ArticleCategory.ArticleCategory1.ID :
                                            (p.ArticleCategory.ArticleCategory1.ArticleCategory1.ParentID == -1 ?
                                            p.ArticleCategory.ArticleCategory1.ArticleCategory1.ID :
                                            p.ArticleCategory.ArticleCategory1.ArticleCategory1.ParentID))
                                            ).SelectMany(p => p.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).Take(2));
```

the ParentID isn't foreign id and no index was used in database.

Comment: Try `.ToList()` before `.GroupBy` and measure time again. Hard to tell where is the bottleneck without using profiler and knowing input data.

Comment: thanks for answer but unfortunately the result is same

Comment: How many items goes to `GroupBy`?

Comment: 211 item (or 211 article) and i have just 8 root category. so the  GroupBy will divide my items to 8 group

Comment: Well that small amount of data should be processed immediately... You must to use profiler to find a bottleneck. Also you can try to add `ToList()` before `SelectMany`.

Comment: you right but other part of my project work well. it load 1.5s without group by. but thanks for your attention!  ;)

Comment: I don't understand. You say that if you remove the grouping, the data load in 100ms. That should be the same as using `ToList` first (actually, `AsEnumerable` would be better). Grouping this amount data in memory should happen in the blink of an eye. So how can it be that *the result is same*?

Comment: ok thank you for attention